Ray serve error: serve.run throws utf-8 can't decode byte 0xf8 in position 0 invalid byte
I am trying to run serve.run in my test method but when the test runs, it throws an error in this part of the code:
serve.run(RayFastApiWrapper.bind(), route_prefix=settings.app_root_url)
FastApiWrapper looks like this:
@serve.deployment(ray_actor_options={"num_gpus": 1, "num_cpus": 8})
@serve.ingress(app)
class RayFastApiWrapper:
    pass

And the module causing the exception seems to be in module ray/_private/accelerators/nvidia_gpu.py
StackTrace:
serve.run(RayFastApiWrapper.bind(), route_prefix=settings.app_root_url)
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ray/serve/api.py:578: in run
    handle = _run(
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ray/serve/api.py:484: in _run
    client = _private_api.serve_start(
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ray/serve/_private/api.py:257: in serve_start
    client = _get_global_client(_health_check_controller=True)
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ray/serve/context.py:87: in _get_global_client
    return _connect(raise_if_no_controller_running)
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ray/serve/context.py:132: in _connect
    ray.init(namespace=SERVE_NAMESPACE)
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ray/_private/client_mode_hook.py:103: in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ray/_private/worker.py:1642: in init
    _global_node = ray._private.node.Node(
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ray/_private/node.py:336: in __init__
    self.start_ray_processes()
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ray/_private/node.py:1396: in start_ray_processes
    resource_spec = self.get_resource_spec()
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ray/_private/node.py:571: in get_resource_spec
    self._resource_spec = ResourceSpec(
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ray/_private/resource_spec.py:215: in resolve
    accelerator_manager.get_current_node_accelerator_type()
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

    @staticmethod
    def get_current_node_accelerator_type() -> Optional[str]:
        import ray._private.thirdparty.pynvml as pynvml
    
        try:
            pynvml.nvmlInit()
        except pynvml.NVMLError:
            return None  # pynvml init failed
        device_count = pynvml.nvmlDeviceGetCount()
        cuda_device_type = None
        if device_count > 0:
            handle = pynvml.nvmlDeviceGetHandleByIndex(0)
            device_name = pynvml.nvmlDeviceGetName(handle)
            if isinstance(device_name, bytes):
>               device_name = device_name.decode("utf-8")
E               UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf8 in position 0: invalid start byte

I am using ray 2.23.0 and gpustat 1.0. However, seems ray uses its own fork of pynvml, judging from the code in the repo.
UPDATE:
Following the comment from @furas, trying to decode with codec utf-16, certainly returns some weird chars:
>>> device_name.decode("utf-16")
'闸膠\uf88e肑要郸膐\uf889낑ꂀ釸膠\uf8a5ꂜ꾁駸膐\uf8a3ꂔꂀ雸膀\uf894낌ꂀ軸肐グ

However, if use the command nvidia-smi directly from the terminal, the device name is correctly obtained:
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 555.42.03              Driver Version: 555.85         CUDA Version: 12.5     |
|-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id          Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |           Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                        |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+========================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090        On  |   00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   35C    P8             16W /  370W |     947MiB /  24576MiB |      2%      Default |
|                                         |                        |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+


error show problem in line device_name.decode("utf-8") - so you could edit source code to check print( device_name ) because it seems device_name uses value which is not utf-8. maybe it helps to explain problem. Maybe it needs only to change some names for devices.

code b'\xf8'.decode('latin1') gives char ø - so maybe you have some device which has ø in name, and it uses latin1 (or similar encodings)

Tried with utf-16... please check the updated post @furas

so it seems devices use strange names and it may need to update source code. Maybe it needs to send info to authors of Ray.

Does this answer your question? UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa5 in position 0: invalid start byte

This appears to a bug of the NVIDIA driver version 555.85. A workaround known so far is to downgrade the NVIDIA driver to before the regression.
References:

https://github.com/wookayin/gpustat/issues/170
https://github.com/XuehaiPan/nvitop/issues/127

